# Xamarin.Forms.Shell: how to manage StatusBar color

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, statusbar, xamarin.forms.shell

I've developed a small **Xamarin.Forms.Shell app** and I didn't found how to apply a **custom color** for the `StatusBar` **Foreground** and **Background**.

My app use a very basic color scheme:

- **black** for the **Foreground** of the `NavigationBar` and the `TabBar`
- **white** for the **Background** of the `NavigationBar` and the `TabBar`

I would like to keep the **same colors** for the `StatusBar`, but it's not the case:

- on **iOS**, the `StatusBar` color seems to be managed by the **LightMode**/**DarkMode**

=> on devices that **doesn't manage DarkMode**, or when **LightMode is active**, the `StatusBar` informations are well displayed
[image: iOS no DarkMode]

=> but it's not the case when the **DarkMode is active**, as these informations are hidden
[image: iOS - DarkMode]

- on **Android**, the `StatusBar` color seems to be managed by the `styles.xaml` file and the `android:statusBarColor` property

=> if I specify a **white** color, the `StatusBar` informations are not visible as there are also white
[image: styles.xaml - white]

=> whereas if I specify a **gray** color, the `StatusBar` informations are well visible
[image: styles.xaml - gray]

So I've tried to apply a solution given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441077/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-without-a-navigation-page):

- **this doens't work** on **iOS**: I still have the same behavior, as the `StatusBar` informations are not visible as there are also white when **DarkMode is active**
- **this seems to work** on **Android**, but this doesn't cover all Android versions (as it works from Marshmallow version)

[image: dependency - white]

**=> How could I manage the iOS StatusBar Foreground color? Is it enough for Android?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following method for iOS (white status bar with black texts)

```
    public void SetWhiteStatusBar()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
            }
            else
            {
                UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
                if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
                {
                    statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                }
            }
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.DarkContent, false);
            GetCurrentViewController().SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
        });
    }
```

Check my question/answer

[Xamarin Forms - how to change the status bar color without a navigation page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441077/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-without-a-navigation-page/58492333?noredirect=1#comment115244304_58492333)

The full working sample is here https://github.com/georgemichailou/ShaXam

Comment: Hi @G.Mich thanks for commenting. I've referred your solution in the description, but I didn't know if I can duplicate the answer: as you did it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

**Op solved the problem by the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58492333/10539446).**

```
public void SetColoredStatusBar(string hexColor)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
            statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(hexColor).ToUIColor();
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
        }
        else
        {
            UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
            if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
            {
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(hexColor).ToUIColor();
            }
        }
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
        GetCurrentViewController().SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
    });
}
```

=========================================================================

Does you app support `dark mode`?

If you app is under `DarkMode`, the status bar text color will change to white. If you does not support Darkmode and still `white for the Background of the NavigationBar and the TabBar`, white text won't visible under white background.

You can use [AppThemeBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#appthemebinding-markup-extension) to set different color under different mode.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=Black}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

If you want to keep the status bar color same under different app theme, use a custom renderer:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ContentPage), typeof(customPageRenderer))]
namespace App479.iOS
{
    public class customPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;

        }

        //if you content page does not have a NavigationBar, oveerride this method
        public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle()
        {
            return UIStatusBarStyle.DarkContent;
        }
    }
}
```

And also add a key to info.plist:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Refer: [preferredstatusbarstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452979/preferredstatusbarstyle-var-not-working-in-ios12)

Comment: Hi @ Jack Hua - MSFT, thanks for your answer. My app doesn't support `DarkMode`, as it embeds an external URL in a WebView, that doesn't manage `DarkMode`. I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work: I still have the informations of the `StatusBar` that are hidden...

Comment: Well, it works on my side. Have a try with return UIStatusBarStyle.DarkContent;. In which device and system are you testing?

Comment: I've tested on an **iPhone XS**, and on a **iPhone 12 Pro simulator**. Finally, I've applied an update of the solution given by [G.Mich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441077/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-without-a-navigation-page). I don't know why your solution didn't work for me: maybe because I use the `Shell`?

Comment: Ok, you can share your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Finally, the solution given in the URL that I shared in the description has been updated and works now on iOS. Do I need to duplicate it?

Comment: I updated my answer with the right solution, you can mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).