# Xamarin Forms How to change Android status bar icon color in API 30 (Android 11)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app being built for iOS and Android.

I'm having some difficulty in Android updating the icon colors when setting the status bar color. I have this working for API levels below 30 using the following code:

```
var isLight = false;

Window currentWindow = Platform.CurrentActivity.Window;

if (Color.FromHex(hexColor).Luminosity > 0.5)
{
    isLight = true;
}

currentWindow.SetStatusBarColor(androidColor);

currentWindow.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = isLight ? (StatusBarVisibility)(SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar) : 0;
```

From what I can tell, DecorView.SystemUiVisibility is deprecated in API 30, and is supposed to be replaced with `window.insetsController`

What I can't figure out is if/where this API is exposed in Xamarin for me to use.

I looked at this SO question:
[How to change the status bar color without a navigation page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441077/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-without-a-navigation-page)

and following the last answer, I attempted to use:

```
var lightStatusBars = isLight ? WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars : 0;

currentWindow.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance((int)lightStatusBars, (int)lightStatusBars);
```

but it will not build, saying Window doesn't have `InsetsController`

Has anyone figured this out? I definitely need to support the latest Android and this feature is killing me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO!. If my answer helps you to solve your issue. Remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Change target framework to Android 11.0 (R). InsetsController was added in API level 30. Due to this you may receive build error.

[image]

```
 public void UpdateStatusBarColor(String color)
  {
      Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.ParseColor(color));
      if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.R)
      {
          Window?.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance((int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars);
      }
      else
      {
          #pragma warning disable CS0618
          Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
          #pragma warning restore CS0618
      }
  }
```

Comment: Originally this wasn't working, but I found out the reason was because Visual Studio has two locations for Build Target, one in Build > General which has the exact phrase in the answer's image and is the right one, and one in Build > Android Application, which is the first one I changed. I made sure both were set to Android 11 R and it works, Thanks Ranjit!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this in MainActivity.cs

$ Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 114, 75, 203));